# What if God created the universe but the Buddha just discovered how it works?

Tags: science

Just like God created The Sims game and the Buddha as a character in it happened to discover how it works by somehow hacking into the program, perhaps by meditation?

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism SE! Since this is not a discussion forum, we prefer adherence to these rules: http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask (To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”)

Comment: Srsly man. I hatez those kind of ignorant questions. It was still fun to dismantle it as a thought experiment.

Comment: I love "what if questions"...they make you think so hard i swear they are good for concentration practice.ahaha.

Comment: @Ahmed I hate to have to interfere, but someone flagged your comment above as "Rude or Offensive". While I personally may or may not disagree with that, this is not the first or even a second time other users find your comments controversial. Whatever side the "truth" is on, the objective situation is, the way you communicate causes some mild disturbance in the community. Please think about this and try to be more agreeable, assuming you want to enjoy being here ;)

Comment: Apologies for my vitriolic humor, I'll be more mindful from now on. I have played countless hours on Sims and other video games and have actually wondered similar things when playing. I should've been more compassionate!
I have found that the most mindless malice that comes out of us is actually due to disliking an aspect of our very own selves and needing to come accord with it... Anyway sorry user17755

Comment: "'The world is swept away. It does not endure': This is the first Dhamma summary stated by the Blessed One who knows & sees, worthy & rightly self-awakened. Having known & seen & heard it, I went forth from the home life into homelessness.

"'The world is without shelter, without protector': This is the second Dhamma summary...

"'The world is without ownership. One has to pass on, leaving everything behind': This is the third Dhamma summary...

"'The world is insufficient, insatiable, a slave to craving': This is the fourth Dhamma summary...

Comment: @Ahmed I thought your first comment was funny. Nice apology though, with good insight as to cause.

Answer (score 2):

**What if God created the universe but the Buddha just discovered how it works?**

Well that's great because after The Buddha discovered how it works he shared with the rest of us how to be free from suffering.

**Note:** He didn't share with us How it All works and who created the universe.
You know why? Because when he was sitting there trying to find the answer to that question he realized oh my god this is going on forever and ever, thats when he realised he had bigger fishes to fry. Like "Suffering and the Cessation of suffering".

In the Sutta [Cula-Malunkyovada Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.063.than.html)here's an explanation of a man who got shot by an arrow and instead of getting help immediately he wanted to know who shot him,what weapon,what clan the shooter came form etc.When he should really be treating the wound.The wound is suffering and we should be treating it instead of trying to find if There's a God or when this universe was created sort of questions.Because it distracting us from the the real problem,that of suffering.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about **a God which is not a being but the cause of all causes** then yes that God is the same as our True Nature or Buddha Nature as Buddha called it.

If you're talking about **a God which created worlds, galaxies, etc.** then that is simply just a God in the form realm or the higher Desire realm heaven. (*See [Thirty-One Planes of Existence](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html).*)

If you're talking about **one specific being created this entire universe** (and all multiverses) including its countless solar systems within countless galaxies... then (1) you need to look at some astronomy videos and (2) the The Buddha specifically says that specific Gods (from the Form and Desire realm heavens) that delight in creation created particular galaxies/places and no one God created every single thing.

He also says that excessive speculation will only waste your time and distract from the actual issue: unhappiness and being trapped in birth-and-death.

Is it more important to be find True Happiness (free of conditions like having physical pleasure, the right relationship, enough money, etc.) and **be able to decide where you go in the universe** or is it more important to spend your life intellectually understand the origin of the universe?

The Buddha emphasized the former and said that the latter would take too long to explain (although he did a good job with the 31 Planes of Existence).

> It's just as if a man were wounded with an arrow thickly smeared with
>   poison. His friends & companions, kinsmen & relatives would provide
>   him with a surgeon, and the man would say, 'I won't have this arrow
>   removed until I know whether the man who wounded me was a noble
>   warrior, a priest, a merchant, or a worker.' He would say, 'I won't
>   have this arrow removed until I know the given name & clan name of the
>   man who wounded me... until I know whether he was tall, medium, or
>   short... until I know whether he was dark, ruddy-brown, or
>   golden-colored... until I know his home village, town, or city...
>   until I know whether the bow with which I was wounded was a long bow
>   or a crossbow... until I know whether the bowstring with which I was
>   wounded was fiber, bamboo threads, sinew, hemp, or bark... until I
>   know whether the shaft with which I was wounded was wild or
>   cultivated... until I know whether the feathers of the shaft with
>   which I was wounded were those of a vulture, a stork, a hawk, a
>   peacock, or another bird... until I know whether the shaft with which
>   I was wounded was bound with the sinew of an ox, a water buffalo, a
>   langur, or a monkey.' He would say, 'I won't have this arrow removed
>   until I know whether the shaft with which I was wounded was that of a
>   common arrow, a curved arrow, a barbed, a calf-toothed, or an oleander
>   arrow.' The man would die and those things would still remain unknown
>   to him. —Cula-Malunkyovada Sutta: The Shorter Instructions to
>   Malunkya" (MN 63), Majjhima Nikaya

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence: what is the "Buddha Nature" which, "as Buddha called it", is "the cause of all causes"? Are you referring to 'the housebuilder' i.e. [Sankhara-khandha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%E1%B9%85kh%C4%81ra#Sankhara-khandha:_The_builder_of_lives)?

Comment: No that's different. [Buddha Nature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddha-nature) (Tathagatagarbha) is what we all have before it was clouded by ignorance and then sankhara-khandha and the rest of causation occured.
We all have Buddha Nature but for an Awakened individual (bodhisattva) it is less clouded to the point that a Buddha has it completely unclouded.
Although Buddha Nature can be referred to as a "God" it is not a creator/destroyer though and is free of will and intention so it's not who the questioner was referring to (Abrahamic type of God).

Answer (score 1):

In a way there ultimately is no Sims. The Buddha taught how one can see past the simulations that we make up and assume are real. This is how we transcend the assumptions we have about suffering and find true peace and happiness :)